# VBA excel. Interacting with Internet Explorer webpage's source

Tags: excel, vba

So I am currently working on a project where I am trying to scrape data from a webpage and export to excel. This question has been explored many times, but I feel one simple question has yet to be answered. A lot of times the source of a webpage "hides" all the useful information.

In my situation, the excel table that I'm trying to pull data from is getting it's data from other online applications. The data is constantly changing everyday and I am trying to develop a tool to get past this.

My attempts at a solution:

1. I figured that I would be able to just pull data from the table and download it directly using this code.

```
For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table") 
    With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
        For Each ERow In .Rows
            For Each ECol In ERow.Cells
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol) = ECol.innerText
                iCol = iCol + 1
             Next ECol
             iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
             iRow = iRow + 1
        Next ERow
    End With
    iTable = iTable + 1
    iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next Tab1
```

This is very useful for people who are dealing with a webpage source that already has the data. If not, you may only see the headers being exported to excel.

2. Maybe performing a kind of "copy and paste" will do.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate Web_URL    
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("k-widget k-reset   k-header k-menu k-context-menu k-menu-vertical")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).ID = "menu" Then ' submit button clicking
        Set objElement = objCollection(i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
objElement.rClick
```

objElement.rClick does not work because it isn't a real command. Another issue with this approach is that the right click menu is actually disabled on the webpage. Performing a right click brings up a new menu so in order to copy massive amount of data you would manually have to highlight and copy everything. This is a tedious process and doing this everyday is not desirable.

My final question: Is there a way to get around this issue. Am I able to scrape data from a website using excel VBA that disables the right click button and doesn't have the data I want contained in the webpage's source?

Comment: Can you share the url with us?

Comment: without an url / html and with no given expected output how can we help?

Comment: your outer loop seems unnecessary as you can simply amend your next loop to cater for all tables. Can you edit your above to one clear question. I want to do this and instead this is happening.... Code should be between code tags (highlight code and press Ctrl+K). HTML should be pasted into snippet tool via [edit].

Comment: Constantly changing every day or throughout the day? If daily this should be a big deal, run it daily and get the new data. If it changes throughout the day you have to either run the subscript at different intervals or dedicate an Excel instance to it and get the data every X time with a timer. VBA attaches itself to the IE window, the IE.document retrieves the information that is currently there, if the table updates live VBA will retrieve whatever is there at that time.

Comment: @dwirony I'm sorry but the webpage isn't public. It is only available on the network I am connected to. I'm trying to find an example that is close.

Comment: @QHarr Reference the comment I made^

Comment: @RicardoA Somewhat both. It is really only vital that we update the data 1 time everyday, but it is a goal to give the option to update during the day.